# How to find number of contributors for a repository?

Tags: github-api

Is there any way to find the number of contributors of a project via the GitHub API? Such information is available on the main page of each project, but it doesn't seem to be present in the API.

For example, we could find the number of contributors on https://github.com/nodejs/node:

[image: Node repo contributor count]

but this key isn't present in https://api.github.com/repos/nodejs/node.

Comment: Did you read the docs? You can get the [contributor list](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-contributors) and then use its length. You will have to deal with paging, though, by the looks of it. In general: if it's not in the API docs, then you can't do it.

Comment: In the case of big projects, as https://github.com/nodejs/node/, we should itterate over all pages, which will provoke many request. Not cleanest way and the risk to be blocked if too much requests. I don't need all data of all contributors, just one simple number.

Comment: Yes, that's what you'll have to do. Read the docs: if they don't list it, you can't get it. In your case you could make two requests: get the first page, get the last page (from the `Link` header), calculate `(first_page_length * (page_count - 1)) + last_page_length`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, didn't understood Your hint about the last page and Link header.

Comment: Per [the API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository), the response includes a `Link` header which contains links to the next *and last* pages of the results. This means that, assuming every other page *except* possibly the last one has as many results as the first page, you can figure out the total count with only two requests.

Comment: I see. Meanwhile Your link point to issues, not contributors. I've found similar Link header in collaborator query : `curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/nodejs/node/contributors`. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Ah it did, sorry; I think that was in my clipboard from your other question! But yes, `/issues` and `/contributors` (like all paginated resources in the GitHub API) both have a `Link` response header.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but it easier to read from page then from API.

Sample with page parsing from https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore using Google Spreadsheet:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML($F2, "//a[contains(text(), 'Contributors')]"),2)
```

You can do the same with any XPath loader.

To do the same from API we need to iterate pages until receive error 404:
https://api.github.com/repos/pimcore/pimcore/contributors?per_page=100&page=1

Documentation is here:
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-repository-contributors

Comment: Google Spreadsheet sample to compare GitHub repositories https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eDbZezk2TcO-AZ4sz1miVEDnZI1Wx_YGRmHscs1Gg_8/edit#gid=0